# How to monitor bandwidth use of each device on dlink 2750u

Tags: router, wireless-router, adsl-router

The method which i saw online is to install custom firmware on your router and to be precise install DD-WRT or TomatoUSB firmware. 
But unfortunately *DD-WRT or TomatoUSB doesnt support D-link 2750u* routers. So is there any another way or firmware (supported by D-link 2750u) to monitor the bandwidth usage by **each** device connected on network.

Comment: Since the router is not supported by DDWRT or Tomato. Your next best bet to monitor Bandwidth would be [DUBandwidthMonitor](http://www.hageltech.com/dumeter/about) but in this case it 30 days free. then you need a license and you can only use it on PC not other devices such as phones or tablets. I would suggest you buy something compatible with [DDWRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices) and use `BWMON` as it works really well even on newest builds.

Comment: The best solution would be to buy a Router like the Asus RT-AC87U. It has the feature you want and much more.

Comment: @Devid Asus RT-AC87U is 10 times more expensive than D-Link 2750u. :/

Comment: Yes, but that is the solution I know and it works well.